# su: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session

Tags: authentication

After configuring the 2 factor authentication I can't login to another user on Ubuntu 14.04.

The changes which I made for 2 factor authentication is

- edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd`; insert at the top this file:

  ```
  auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
  ```
- edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`; insert before the `pam_unix` line:

  ```
  auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
  ```

Only if I comment out these lines can I login as another user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add every user you want to authenticate with to your Google Authenticator app.

What I suggest is first add 2FA for your `root` user. From `root` you can `su` to any account without authentication at all. So when you have 2FA for `root` you just `su` to each user and then `exit`.

If you don't want to have 2FA for `root` you can check out [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo) - section "Setting up the app" shows you what to do if you already have 2FA for one user.